# Html class changing is failing

Tags: html, dom, django-templates, font-awesome

I am initializing icons based on different outcomes in Django template. Here is my code

```
{% if name == 'Euro' %}
         <i class="fa fa-eur"></i>
{% else %}
         <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>
{% endif %}
```

Problem is whatever the outcome is, icon class is remaining **fa fa-shopping-bag** . I have checked **if/else** conditional, it is working perfectly. What is the cause of this phenomenon? How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you post more of the code, like where name gets set?

Comment: If you just output `name` above the conditional, are you sure it's set to 'Euro'?